Loading serialized nested tuples using pydantic models
Consider the following nested-tuple type Prop and a pydantic model using it:
Prop = tuple[tuple[str, str], ...]

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    prop: dict[Prop, list[float]]

Serializing the model works just fine:
dumped = MyModel(prop={(("a", "A"), ("b", "V")): [0.0, 1.1]}).model_dump(
    mode="json"
)
# returns {'prop': {'a,A,b,V': [0.0, 1.1]}}

But if I load the dumped dictionary back in, I get a ValidationError:
MyModel(**dumped)
# pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyModel prop.a,A,b,V.[key]
# Input should be a valid tuple [type=tuple_type, input_value='a,A,b,V', input_type=str]

I expected the model_dump to produce output that can be read back in, but this is not the case.  Is there an easy work around?
mode="json" is required to deal with dates.  The Prop type is used extensively throughout my application, so manually serializing/deserializing it or annotating it in every pydantic model that uses it would be very annoying.

def pre_validate_prop(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        res = tuple(zip(s.split(",")[::2], s.split(",")[1::2]))
    elif isinstance(s, tuple):
        res = s
    elif isinstance(s, list):
        res = tuple(tuple(e) for e in s)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown type for validation of prop {s}")
    return res


PropAnnotation = Annotated[
    Prop,
    BeforeValidator(pre_validate_prop),
]

Using Annotated and BeforeValidator, I could introduce a type that wraps around my original Prop type but implements the proper deserialization behavior.  Because models can also be initialized from code, I'm adding fallback handling for when the input is already a tuple (and edge case handling for lists).
